# ORDER BY date DESC d-m-Y

Tags: php, mysql, date

***EDIT***
The format in the .csv excel file for the date was 15-12-2011 and in the MySQL phpmyadmin database the column type was set to DATE so if I imported the file all data in date column changed to 0000-00-00. I did the next to fix this, went into the .csv file and selected the column for date and changed the format to 'Africa' so it would change everything from d-m-Y to Y-m-d. So in the .csv it would become 2011-12-15 instead of 15-12-2011. After importing it again the date was correctly imported without turning to 0000-00-00.

After that I Changed the ORDER BY in index.php:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `newitems` ORDER BY startVisible DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

After that I changed the format date where was needed.

```
Available from: <?php 
                        $timestamp = strtotime($query_row["startVisible"]);
                        echo date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
                        ?>
```

These scripts would first change the order by 1.year 2.month 3.day and after that change the format so it would echo 15-12-2011 instead of 2011-12-15 (how it is saved in the database)

Hope this will help others with the same problem.

Cheers.

**below = question I asked**

I have exported a table and modified some things that needed to be modified. Next I tried to import them into the table again but `startVisible` column Type was set to date. All my dates where stored as 0000-00-00. All my dates in the csv file are like 15-12-2011. I've changed the column Type to varchar and after that I could import the csv file with everything as 15-12-2011 I wanted to sort everything by date in www.domain.com/index.php. That is because the column type is not set to DATE. So I Changed the Column type from VARCHAR to DATE again and all the dates changed to 0000-00-00.
So no matter what I did everything changed to 0000-00-00. I removed everything and imported the same file and all the dates where imported correctly. So it may be a MySQL load fail or something.

I used:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newItems ORDER BY startVisible DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

But all the dates are mixed now. It has to short them by d-m-Y but does not do that.

```
9-8-2011
9-3-2011
8-3-2011
7-6-2011
7-3-2011
7-11-2011
6-7-2011
```

Now everything is sorted correctly but I want to change the order it shows from 2011-12-15 to 15-12-2011. ( I MEAN ON THE WEBSITE not in MySQL ). in index.php I want to show everything as d-m-Y but I still want to sort (ORDER BY) them correctly. How to do that?

Thanks,
F4LLCON

Comment: _I've changed the column Type to varchar_, Change the column type back to `date` type

Comment: @Shakti Singh: doesn't look like a format that would be accepted by date column's, though (wrong order, and day and month not padded with 0 to 2 digits)

Comment: That does not work, if I change the type back to date, everything will turn into 0000-00-00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the query is now ordered by a `varchar` column so it is sorted alphabetically, So try to convert it to a date first:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(startVisible, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d-%m-%Y') as startDate,... 
from newItems 
ORDER BY startDate DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page;
```

Comment: I tried to convert it from varchar to date, but it converter all the data to 0000-00-00. Not working, tried already.

Comment: @F4LLCON try the formula `'%d-%M-%Y'`

Comment: @F4LLCON sorry it is m small like `'%d-%m-%Y'` i edited my answer

Comment: Oke everything in column startVisible changed from 15-12-2011 to 2011-12-15 but the column type is still varchar. Now on the website if I use ORDER BY startDate DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page; in index.php on the website it sorts them but shows them like 2011-12-15. How to fix that so it shows 15-12-2011? btw. I used select STR_TO_DATE(startVisible, '%d-%m-%Y') from newItems

Comment: @F4LLCON try to enclose it with `DATE_FORMAT( ,'%d-%m-%Y')`, see my edit.

Comment: You mean in MySQL SQL Query right? The date in MySQL column needs to show like 2011-12-15 and on my website it has to show like 15-12-2011 but still sort them correct. That is because the iPhone app we already have is modified to show them like that, so I don't want to change that. How to fix this in index.php? I've changed my question above. Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you just use the formula `'%Y-%m-%d'` to select it like 2011-12-15 in your index.php

Comment: Hmm... I don't follow you anymore, my code I use in index.php is `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newItems ORDER BY year(startVisible) desc, month(startVisible) DESC, day(startVisible) desc LIMIT $start, $per_page");` It shows 2011-12-15 in good order. But I want to change it from Y-m-d to d-m-Y IN index.php not mysql. How?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5872/discussion-between-f4llcon-and-mga)

Comment: Hey, everything is fixed now, I've updated my question above with what I did. Thanks bye :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try MySQL function STR_TO_DATE. Here is an example query.

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(dt,'%d-%m-%Y') AS fmtDate, dt FROM test.text ORDER BY  fmtDate

Prasad.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the fact the column is no longer a date, and therefore cannot be sorted as a date.  You've mentioned that it is now a `VARCHAR`.  Ergo, it will sort alphabetically, not as a date.

Comment: I Know but if the colum type was set to DATE, I could not import the date data. It would change 31-11-2011 to 0000-00-00. I changed DATE to VARCHAR so the date would be added. If I change VARCHAR to DATE after the date data is imported it will still change everything from 31-11-2011 to 0000-00-00. Know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

The type is currently varchar, so it will use text sorting.

My advise is to add a column to your table of type date, fill it by converting the date-strings to proper dates using [str-to-date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and then sort on that column. (To really do d-m-y you probably have to use

```
ORDER BY day(datecolumn) desc, month(datecolumn) desc, year(datecolumn) desc
```

But are you sure you don't just mean `ORDER BY datecolumn DESC` - most recent first?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the columns using [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Do this.

1. Convert and update the columns using STR_DO_DATE[1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
2. Alter the column to date type.

Comment: STR_TO_DATE('startVisible','%d/%m/%Y') like this? Does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in Laravel then use like this below

```
$covid19Result = DB::select('select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_field_name,"%d-%m-%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d") as startDate, active_people, death_people, recover_people from covid_graphs ORDER BY startDate DESC');
```

It works fine for me

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, it will be useful to create a function (or a trigger), and use it when you need :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS makedate;

CREATE FUNCTION makedate(your_field VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_field, '%d/%m/%Y' ) , '%Y-%m-%d' );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ajreal please let me know which was the nature of your edit to my post and also way did you vote my post down, in order to understand... for the future

Comment: no, I dun bother to vote down. I do edit is because you have an ugly format.

Comment: could you explain "ugly format" I really don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I understand now, it was a simple copy-paste from notepad, and I forgot to "beautify" it here. Thks.